# Energy and Momentum: Impact

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, energy-conservation, momentum, collision

> Boat A has just lost another race to Boat B. In a fit of rage, the driver of Boat A (mass = 500 kg) turns his boat towards Boat B (mass = 450 kg) which is at rest as the driver gloats over yet another victory. If Boat A has a speed of 25 m/s just before impact, what are the velocities of the two boats after the collision, if the collision is elastic. How much kinetic energy is lost in the collision?

Here is my drawing (NOTE: The 25 should be negative!)

[image]

I used the elastic collection formula to get the final velocity of each one and got (using boat A as mass 1 and boat B as mass 2)

$V_{1F} = -1.316\ \mathrm{m/s} $ or $1.316\ \mathrm{m/s}$ in the left direction

$V_{2F} = -2.632\ \mathrm{m/s}$ or $2.632\ \mathrm{m/s}$ in the left direction

So the next part of the question asks:

> How much kinetic energy is lost in the collision?

And in my notes I have it written that in an elastic collision, both kinetic energy and momentum are conserved, so applying that here, that would mean that no kinetic energy was lost during the collision, right?

Comment: Could you specify which elastic formula you are using please? Since the collision is elastic both momentum and energy are conserved by definition. Have toy taken that into account in your calculation of the velocities?

Comment: This offends my sense of what a well written exercise should be because a ~80 km-per-hr (~50 mph) collision between boats is unlikely to be elastic in the real world. I like question to have some relation to the students experience of the world. We now return you to your regularly scheduled Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. No kinetic energy is lost in the collision, since the collision is said to be elastic. Quoting from Wikipedia:

> An elastic collision is an encounter between two bodies in which the total kinetic energy of the two bodies after the encounter is equal to their total kinetic energy before the encounter. Elastic collisions occur only if there is no net conversion of kinetic energy into other forms.

See [Elastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) for more.

Cheers!